# How to retrieve user's follower's profiles using angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I am trying to retrieve user's follower's profiles and store them in $scope.object so that I can use in ng-repeat.
My firebase structure looks like this,

```
users
  - user_id:
       - name:
       -followers: 
           - follower: user_id1
           - follower: user_id2...
       -following :
```

right now I can get the list of user_ids from followers section, What I want is to retrieve their profiles/details from **users** section.
This is what I tried,

```
 $scope.followers = [];
$scope.profile.$loaded().then(function() {
           $scope.profile.followers);   
          angular.forEach()
           angular.forEach($scope.profile.followers, function(value, key) {

                var followerID = value.follower;
                userProfile = Profile(followerID);  // retrieve firebaseobject profile from factory
                 $scope.followers.push(angular.extend({}, userProfile));
                  console.log($scope.followers);

           });
         }); console.log($scope.followers);
```

No when I see the output in console I can see their profile/details inside **forEach** loop but $scope.followers is empty outside the loop.
I am not sure if its the best practice in terms of firebase and or angularJS. Can somebody please point me in right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a asynchronous `$scope.profile.$loaded()` which is returning promise. And you are trying to access `$scope.followers` object outside the ajax success, which will `[]` at anytime. The reason is object is getting filled inside success function `forEach` loop.

You need to put `console.log($scope.followers);` inside `.then` function so that you could get `followers`

**Code**

```
$scope.followers = [];
$scope.profile.$loaded().then(function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.profile.followers,
        function(value, key) {

            var followerID = value.follower;
            userProfile = Profile(followerID); // retrieve firebaseobject profile from factory
            $scope.followers.push(angular.extend({}, userProfile));
            console.log($scope.followers);

        }); 
    //should inside then to get value which is comming asynchronusly
    console.log($scope.followers);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response @pankajparkar ,
However what I want is,
1) I need to use `$scope.followers' in my html's `ng-repeat` Thats why I tried console.log outside `.then`
2) In you solution, when I print `userProfile` It shows correct values i.e profile details of  like name, followers etc. for that particular user. but then I try to add it to `$scope.followers` and print it shows only their ids same as `var followerID` .
which is not what I want, I want `$scope.follower` with list of profile's details and not just their ids.